# Swift 4.2, Xcode 10.2 nil coalescing operator warning

Tags: ios, swift, xcode10.2

On `Xcode 10.1`, the following statement wasn't having any issues, but after updating the `Xcode` to `10.2` compiler is generating warning for the statement.

```
return [
    "sublevels": (self.sublevels?.array ?? [Sublevel]()) as NSObject
]
```

`sublevels` is `NSOrderedSet`, and the warning generated is as follows:

```
Left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type '[Any]?', so the right side is never used
```

But if I break the single statement as follows, the warning disappears.

```
let sublevels = self.sublevels?.array ?? [Sublevel]()
return [
    "sublevels": sublevels as NSObject
]
```

Please, will anyone explain - what is the issue with the first statement ?

Comment: A (minimal) *self-contained* compiling example would be helpful.

Comment: I think the error message should be reported as a bug. `[Any]?` definitely is an Optional. But you need to supply some `[Any]` as the left hand side of `??` is of type `[Any]?`. What if you replace `?? [Sublevel]()` to `?? []` ?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a bug, regarding the [SE-0054](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0054-abolish-iuo.md) rules. `Any` is optional, as long as `Any` has no type basically.

Comment: @Craz1k0ek, SE-0054 is describing about ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional, and `[Any]?` aka `Optional<Array<Any>>` is a normal Optional and nothing described in SE-0054 applies to normal Optional. Are you mistaking with some other proposal?

Comment: @OOPer ah yeah, you’re right. Was a bit quick. Better would be to link to [type casting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by OOPer, the solution is to provide a default `Any` value as right hand side of the operator, in this case an `[Any]`, because the `NSOrderedSet` has no specific type bound to it. The solution is:

```
return [
    "sublevels": (self.sublevels?.array ?? []) as NSObject
]
```

For more info on this matter I suggest you take a look at [type casting](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html). At the bottom of the page there is an explanation about casting the `Any` type.